# Jquery - Textbox having two values which are uneditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, textbox

Original Design:

[image]

Desired Design:

[image]

I want to have a Textbox having Predefined characters SD and users can add another characters or numbers. But SD cannot be deleted nor edited. Is it possible? 

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around like this

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <input type="text" style="padding-left:25px" />
    <span style="position: absolute; padding: 3px 0; left: 5px">SD</span>
</div>
```

don't forget to change the padding and left values to suit your font and size.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment a bit with two inputs and removed left / right borders. A quick solution I just created may look like this:

CSS:

```
input {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
input[readonly] {
    border-right: 0;
    width: 20px;
}
input:not([readonly]) {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="SD" readonly="readonly"><input type="number" value="123">
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/9593231

It is up to you to adapt this to your overall design.